# How to use variable inside JSON file as prefix

Tags: json

I have the a JSON file and a need to add a prefix variable in some fields, but did not work pass the variable using $variable, {variable}, etc.

My Original JSON file is shown below.

```
{
    "SETUP": {
        "mission": "P:\Project",
        "mission_type": "0",
        "fortnight": "25",
        "tide": "0"
    },
        
    "MISSION":  {
        "INPUT": {
            "arms": "\cp\arms.ini",
        },
}
```

I need to add the SETUP.mission prefix to the field Mission.INPUT.arms

```
{
    "SETUP": {
        "mission": "P:\Project",
        "mission_type": "0",
        "fortnight": "25",
        "tide": "0"
    },
        
    "MISSION":  {
        "INPUT": {
            "arms": SETUP.mission + "\cp\arms.ini",
        },
}
```

**MISSION.INPUT.arms = "P:\Project\cp\arms.ini"**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON doesn't have a concept of variables. What you need to do is to load it on memory, modify it and save back to the file if needed.
Here's an example of doing it in Node.js:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const json = require('./path/to/json/file.json');

json.MISSION.INPUT.arms = path.join(json.SETUP.mission, json.MISSION.INPUT.arms);

fs.writeFileSync('./path/to/json/file.json', JSON.stringify(json));
```

Comment: Thank you, I am thinking about it. Every solution that I saw was using code. I looking for a solution without external stuffs. I will change to XML maybe. Thank you for the help